# How to run a "Keep NumLock always on" command in Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon on each reboot / re-login?

Tags: linux-mint, startup, cinnamon, reboot, numlock

In an answer of my question on Code Review:

[Keep NumLock always on in Linux (C++)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147817/104270),

I am pointed to the right solution for this problem, that being a command:

```
setxkbmap -option numpad:mac
```

which proves to work when I invoke it from logged in session.

---

I am trying to invoke it on each reboot / re-login.

So far, my best guess was to edit my user's `crontab`:

```
$ crontab -l

@reboot /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option numpad:mac
```

But this does not seem to work for some reason.

---

Just to note that this is not a duplicate of questions formulated like *How to keep NumLock always on*.

---

I have now tried to add a little (from terminal working shell script) to Startup Applications to no avail:

[image: NumLock script in Startup Applications]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a **Startup Delay** to that Startup Applications entry did help.

I am unsure, why it is necessary or how low I can set it, nor if that is individual to a system, so a better answer explaining these things might be welcome.